# How to remove ticktypes with prespbox() (plot3d)

Tags: r, plot3d

I am trying to construct a 3d-plot with grid lines using the function `prespbox()` and adding an additional plot of a figure based on some data using the `surf3d()` function.

This is my code:

```
library(plot3D) # added by comment

perspbox (x = seq(0.05, 0.5, length.out = nrow(M$x)), 
      y = seq(0.05, 0.5, length.out = ncol(M$y)), z, 
      bty = "u", 
      col.axis = "black", col.panel = "white", lwd.panel = 1,                     
      col.grid = "grey", lwd.grid = 1, las=1,
      phi = 40, theta = 40, col = NULL,ps=30,
      nticks=4, ticktype="detailed", xlab="\n\n h1", ylab="\n\n h2", zlab="\n\n Fund",
      colkey = TRUE,cex.axis=0.5, plot = TRUE)
surf3D(M$x, M$y, z, colvar = z, colkey = TRUE,add=TRUE)
```

My problem is, that the tick lines at the axis are too long.

Do you have an idea, how I could get rid of the tick lines? I want to keep the axis labels, but completely remove the tick lines. I already tried the `tck` option, but it seems not to have any effect here.

Comment: IYes doesnt appear `tcl` or `tck`  has any effect, either as parameters or by setting the global value. Ive not really gone through it but this seems to offere a way to customise `persp` http://entrenchant.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673018/plot3d-how-to-change-box-color-and-remove-axis-ticks?rq=1) can help?