# Remove axes ticks using plot3d in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rgl

I am trying to render a 3D cube with spheres plotted inside.
I am using RGL library in R and rendering with plot3d
I would like to keep all 12 axes lines, but remove the tick marks.

This is the code I have:

```
library(rgl)

rgl.open()
rgl.bg(color='white')

a <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.1)
b <- c(0.1, 0.9, 0.9)
c <- c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1)

xlab="z"
ylab="y"
zlab="x"
type="s"
col="red"
size=3

plot3d(a, b, c, xlab, ylab, zlab, type, col, size, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), zlim=c(0,1), aspect=c(3,3,3), main="", sub="", ann=FALSE, axes=TRUE)
```

Output:
[image]

I have tried using this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673018/plot3d-how-to-change-box-color-and-remove-axis-ticks) as a solution, but I cannot get the axes lines to appear, while making sure the cube is transparent.

The code below is based off the aforementioned post:

```
plot3d(xvar, yvar, zvar, type = 's', col = colgroup, size = 0.05, alpha = 0.50, 
       radius = 0.2, xlab = 'Cost Leader', ylab = 'Performance Leader', 
       zlab = 'Fashion Leader', axes = FALSE)
rgl.bbox(xlen = 0, ylen = 0, zlen = 0, color = c('grey100'), alpha=0.5, axes=TRUE)
text3d(x = xvar, y = yvar, z = zvar, text = brands, adj = c(2.5,2.5), cex = 0.7)
```

I have tried adding `alpha` arguement but this is the output (one of them):

[image]

Any input is appreciated. This seemingly simple issue has caused a fair amount of head scratching.

TLDR: How to make transparent cube with points and xyz axes labeled. (No ticks).

R version: 3.5.1
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

P.S. Couldn't make new tag for plot3d .. hence they are split...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unrelated to your question, but it's important:  don't use `rgl.open()` or `rgl.bg()` or `rgl.bbox()`.  They will just cause trouble for you.  Use `open3d()` and `bg3d()` and `bbox3d()`.

Also unrelated, but I think this is good advice:  don't use functions with long argument lists without naming the arguments.  It's too easy to have unnamed args matched to the wrong thing.

As to your question:  do the plot with no axes, then add the nonstandard axes you want.  Since you don't really want anything there, use just `box3d()` to draw the box.  For example,

```
library(rgl)
open3d()
bg3d(color = "white")

a <- c(0.9, 0.9, 0.1)
b <- c(0.1, 0.9, 0.9)
c <- c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1)

xlab <-"z"
ylab <- "y"
zlab <- "x"
type <- "s"
col <- "red"
size <- 10

plot3d(a, b, c, 
      xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, zlab = zlab, 
      type = type, col = col, 
      xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), zlim = c(0,1), 
      aspect = c(3,3,3), 
      size = size,
      main = "", sub = "", ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE)
box3d()
```

This produces

[image: screenshot]